# Google Vizualization Charts - Save to File

Tags: asp.net, google-visualization

I am using Google Vizualization API to create an organization chart.
The API itself does not seem to have a feature to save charts to JPEG, PDF etc.
What options do I have to save the chart to file?  [this file will be sent as an email attachment]

Comment: easier, use straight image charts rather than going through another step. see http://datamakessense.com/kpi-emails-with-google-charts-url-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great guide to saving gviz charts as images [here](http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html) and a corresponding [github gist](https://gist.github.com/1333906). It works with SVG charts from the gviz series (note, no Flash).

Answer (score 0):

You can't save the org chart as an image or PDF.

Unlike some of the other Google charts, the code for this creates divs on the page.

If you're not looking for an automated process, you could just take a screenshot of the chart, save it as an image & email it as an attachment.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html

---

Since you want it automated, the only solution I can think of is a third party control..and you'll probably have to pay for it.
Not many companies make org chart controls..even the popular companies like Telerik & Dundas have not ventured into it yet.

NWoods has a diagram control:
http://www.nwoods.com/components/dotnet/godiagram-overview.htm

There's another at orgchartcomponent.com
http://www.orgchartcomponent.com/doc.aspx

You'll probably have to check the documentation on how the charts are rendered.

If they are images, you can save it as a file.

Comment: I am looking for an automated process.

Comment: Added 3rd party controls to answer.